# How to add OFL link in Firebase dynamic linking iOS Swift?

Tags: swift, swift3

How to add OFL link in Firebase dynamic linking iOS Swift?
open a Firebase dynamic link in desktop, to redirect a particular website Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    guard let link = URL(string: "url") else { return }
    let dynamicLinksDomainURIPrefix = "prefixlik"
    guard let shareLink = DynamicLinkComponents(link: link, domainURIPrefix: dynamicLinksDomainURIPrefix) else {
        print("Could not create firebace dynamiclink on console")
        return
    }
    if let myBundleId = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier {
        shareLink.iOSParameters = DynamicLinkIOSParameters(bundleID: myBundleId)
    }
    shareLink.iOSParameters?.appStoreID = "XXXXXXXXX"
    shareLink.androidParameters = DynamicLinkAndroidParameters(packageName: "XXXXXXXX")
    guard let longDynamicLink = shareLink.url else { return }
    print("The long URL is: \(longDynamicLink)")
    DynamicLinkComponents.shortenURL(URL(string: "\(longDynamicLink)&ofl=https://google.com/")!, options: nil) { (url, warnings, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Oh no! Got an error ",error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        if let warnings = warnings {
            for warning in warnings {
                print("FDL warning: \(warning)")
            }
        }
        guard let shortUrl = url else {return}
        print(shortUrl) }
```